# Whitespace below application - Ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ember.js, handlebars.js

I haven't been able to find an answer for this question yet, so maybe no one is having it. *I'm pretty sure its impossible to replicate on a jsfiddle.*

So, I have a page that gets a *little* long, probably 2200-2500px. But when a user hits submit on the page (located at the **bottom** of the page), they are left with a white screen and a navbar (something that's at the top of the page). That's the description I'm getting from users that are not computer literate...

**As it turns out, when ember removes the route from the application outlet, its not removing the space below so there's a large whitespace below the next page causing users to have to scroll up to see the next page content.**

I am programatically calling ex.`route.transitionTo('page-after-submit');`. I'm not sure if there's a bug or something in Ember itself causing this issue. *Anyone know?*

### Extra info:

- Structure of the page is `ApplicationView->SignUpRouteView` transitioning to `ApplicationView->NewUserView`.
- Ember Version: **v1.3.0**
- Handlebars Version: **v1.1.2**

Pic of the phenomenon:
[image: whitespace]

Comment: What happens if you simply do a `.focus()` on the highest up div?

Comment: Oddly enough, it does the same thing except puts the page a little higher up.

Comment: @gravityplanx Added a pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is 'normal' behavior - Ember preserves the scroll position when you change routes. To change that include the following in your `ApplicationController`

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentPathChanged: function() {
    if (window) window.scrollTo(0, 0);  
  }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

This will scroll to the top of the page every time you transition between routes

Comment: chopper, we meet again. This seems like a hack more than a fix, but it works.